# Boot error after upgrading to 23.04, pcie:hp: cannot get irq -1 for the hotplug controller

Tags: boot, hotplug

I upgraded from 22.10 to 23.04, now when I boot in to Ubuntu I get the error:

pcie:hp: cannot get irq -1 for the hotplug controller

pciehp: Notification initialization failed (-1)

What's very strange is that I run Ubuntu recovery mode from GRUB, and 'boot as normal', I login and everything is fine.

I have run Boot Repair to no avail, and googled the error message, however this is the first time where it only returned one result! (where the guy changed version of ubuntu to fix!).

Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: as of around 11 jul my system boots fine now. Some update along the way must have fixed it.

Comment: I'm fighting the same issue. What CPU, motherboard, and video are you using? My new build with this issue: Intel Core i5-13600K, Gigabyte Z790 AORUS ELITE AX (rev 1.1), Gigabyte RTX 4070 Windforce OC 12G

Comment: Identical specs minus the graphics card. Interesting.

Comment: I'm able to boot up when I make the nvidia card the primary display adapter, but I'm wanting to use the integrated video for the primary and the GPU for AI/ML stuff. Also, I just flashed the bios a few mins ago with no change. Do you have a discreet video card or just using the integrated?

Comment: I was able to boot using the integrated video from the usb drive I used to install. Interestingly, it flashed the same error for a moment before making it to the "try it" desktop. Although the nvidia card isn't displaying anything yet of course. My DMs are open on Twitter (@brian_jorden) if you are up for chatting about this for a min, I would have a couple questions. I'll post here if I sort anything out or make progress though.

Comment: AFAIK my GPU is the primary display adapter. In NVIDIA X Server settings under my graphics card it says: display devices: <lists my monitors> yet I am having this problem. How do I make sure the NVIDIA card is the primary display adapter? I don't have twitter, sorry.

Comment: I'm curious, what video card are you using? I'm worried this is because the cpu/motherboard/video are all super new and so is 23.04, but maybe the drivers aren't all caught up yet. Was this working on 22.10 for you? I might revert to the LTS version for now... Oh, can set initial display adapter to be integrated or one of the PCIe slots in the bios under settings / io ports.

Comment: Hi, not a brand new one like yours. Nvidia though. I would guess that its the mobo/cpu as that's whats similar here. The primary display adapter was set to (I believe, need to check) the correct PCIe slot. For furhter measure I disabled integrated graphics and still had the same error. So slightly different 'fixes' for both of us here.

Comment: Hi mate, did you find any solution?

Comment: Not really, I just switched off the integrated video and running from the Nvidia card for now. I'm going to be setting up a dual boot to windows, but will give me a chance to try the LTS version of kubuntu instead to see if it is still a problem there. I'm kinda guessing this is a driver and/or version issue.

Comment: Hmm that didn't fix it for me. I'll try again. I am not very good at this stuff!

Comment: I wouldn't say I have any answers, but I can confirm this is no issue in Windows 11 for me. I set up a dual boot of Windows 11 / Kubuntu and Windows doesn't seem to care or have any issues. I'm actually able to run one monitor from the integrated card and one from the nvidia without any issue. At this point my guess is there might be an issue with the driver being used for the integrated video on this super new version of ubuntu/kubuntu.

Comment: Yep, I can boot to windows just fine too. I have been unfortunately just booting in to recovery mode every time then booting from there as I haven't been able to fix it!

Comment: My system boots fine now. I'm not sure what changed, perhaps some kernel update, but all is well now!